# Handle property with different types in a POCO

Tags: c#

I usually receive a json response from an API

```
{
  "errors": "Error message"
}
```

My issue is that the same api can return me some other response with another format :

```
{
  "errors": [
     { "message": "error message 1", "description": "error description 1" },
     { "message": "error message 2", "description": "error description 2" }
  ]
}
```

My issue is that i have to deserialize this response and map it to an object in order to return it with some formatting.

```
namespace namespace.models
{
    public class ErrorResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "errors")]
        public ErrorDetail[] Errors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use the following code to handle a post request :

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); 
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(
         JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), 
         Encoding.UTF8, 
         "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    string output = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
    PostResponse returnValue = new PostResponse ();
    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)201)
    {
        returnValue.Id = Int32.Parse(output);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(output)
        throw new Exception(httpResponse.ReasonPhrase + " " + output);
    }
    return returnValue;
```

}

My issue is that idon't know how to handle a response that can be a string and then my exception should be the "output" i received, or an array of object. Should i return this as string too ?
Or is there a way to handle the reponse differently ?

Comment: You can first try to deserialize to array, then to string (try, catch). If you get a string you create an `ErrorDetail[]` with one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to easily Deserialize here using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. It could be done with the custom converter but for me, it is too much hassle.

Luckily you could easily parse the response into `JObject`, then check the type of `JToken` and convert them to the required type like so

```
var json1 = "{\r\n  \"errors\": \"Error message\"\r\n}";
var json2 = "{\r\n  \"errors\": [\r\n     { \"message\": \"error message 1\", \"description\": \"error description 1\" },\r\n     { \"message\": \"error message 2\", \"description\": \"error description 2\" }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

var jo = JObject.Parse(json2);

var errResponse = new ErrorResponse();

if (jo["errors"] is JArray array)
{
    errResponse.Errors = array.ToObject<ErrorDetail[]>() ?? Array.Empty<ErrorDetail>();
}
else
{
    errResponse.Errors = new[] { new ErrorDetail() { Message = jo["errors"]?.Value<string>() ?? string.Empty } };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string output = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)201)
{
        returnValue.Id = Int32.Parse(output);
}
    else
{

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(output);

var errorResponse = jsonObject["errors"].GetType().Name == "JArray" ? 
jsonObject2.ToObject<ErrorResponse>() :
new ErrorResponse { Errors = new ErrorDetail[] 
{ new ErrorDetail { Message = (string)jsonObject["errors"], Description="Short error format" } } };
        
throw new Exception(httpResponse.ReasonPhrase + "  " 
+ string.Join("; \r\n", errorResponse.Errors.Select(i=> "Message: "+ i.Message 
+ " Description: "+i.Description)); );

}
  return returnValue;
```

or you can use this code as well

classes

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
        [JsonProperty("errors")]
        public ErrorDetail[] Errors { get; set; }
}
 
public partial class ErrorDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created two classes and use try catch.
One is having a member errors declared as string and the second has an array of object.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json1 = "{\r\n  \"errors\": \"Error message\"\r\n}";
    var json2 = "{\r\n  \"errors\": [\r\n     { \"message\": \"error message 1\", \"description\": \"error description 1\" },\r\n     { \"message\": \"error message 2\", \"description\": \"error description 2\" }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

   try
   {
       ErrorsResponse response = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorsResponse>(json1);
       Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       ErrorResponse response = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(json1);
       Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
   }
}
```

I didn't try the other solution. I'm going to test them.